# OutOfMemoryError: backgroud drawable - Android

Tags: android, view, background, drawable

Help me!
I create an android project with

MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and a view activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bg_1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_1" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bg_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_2"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bg_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Drawable folder contains three images:
bg_1.jpg (66k),
bg_2.jpg (190k),
bg_3.jpg (48k)

It seem simple, but it throw errors when running:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:514)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:359)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:786)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1969)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3353)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3290)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:409)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2087)
            at com.example.hoa.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5238)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4904)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Someone give me the cause and the solution? **Thank you so much!**

Comment: Sounds like you are loading some huge backgrounds and the device does not have enough memory for them

Answer (score 1):

Your images may not seem big because of their size but it's the resolution that matters. You can either scale them down yourself, or you can set the images programatically and try using this method below:

```
// Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
try {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale = 1;
    while(o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && 
          o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
return null;
}
```

There's a nice read here too:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Make different image sizes on different screen densities (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi etc.).

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce the size of your images.Its seems you device is running low on memory